# Angular 2 router alternate syntaxes for routerLink directive not working

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm trying to get the `routerLink` directive to work with matrix parameters. So far the only syntax variant that I've been able to get working is simply the path string.

```
<a routerLink="/state-scratchpad">Syntax 1 - works</a>
<a routerLink="['/state-scratchpad']">Syntax 2 - doesn't work</a>
<a routerLink="['/state-scratchpad', { tcomp: '1', tmake: '1-7' }]">Syntax 3 - doesn't work</a>
<a routerLink="/state-scratchpad;tcomp=1;tmake=8">Syntax 4 - doesn't work</a>
```

Navigating in the URL bar to `/state-scratchpad;tcomp=1;tmake=8` also works.

Here are my routes:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/welcome' },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'state-scratchpad', component: StateScratchpadComponent, params: { tcomp: '', tmake: '' } }
];
```

I'm using Angular `2.0.0`. According to the documentation on the [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html) site the various syntaxes for `routerLink` values should all work. But only the simplest syntax works. Here are the resulting error messages:

```
S1: Works
S2: Error: Cannot match any routes: '%5B'/state-scratchpad'%5D'
S3: Error: Cannot match any routes: '%5B'/state-scratchpad'%2C%20%7B%20tcomp%3A%20'1'%2C%20tmake%3A%20'1-7'%20%7D%5D'
S4: Error: Cannot match any routes: 'state-scratchpad%3Btcomp%3D1%3Btmake%3D8'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[routerLink]="..."`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a router link looks like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/state-scratchpad', tcomp, tmake]">
```

This will pass the base url and append the params.
Next your route should look like this

```
{ path: 'state-scratchpad/:tcomp/:tmake', component: StateScratchpadComponent}
```

Then when the component is loaded you access the params like this

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit(){ 
    this.route.snapshot.params["tcomp"];
    this.route.snapshot.params["tmake"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was making a simple first-time user's mistake. As far as the params go, I'm using matrix params here rather than positional params.

But what I want achieve is binding the `routerLink` value to a path-segment observable. Something like this: 

`<a [routerLink]="${somePath$} | async">Some Link</a>`

But I'm not sure what the proper syntax is to get this working.